# Survey JS get survey results response in Json instead of XML

Tags: javascript, json, xml, surveyjs

I am trying to get the results of the surveys in JSON, but the API is giving the response in XML. The API lists that json response is also available but which attribute do I have to use while making the request is nowhere to be found.

https://surveyjs.io/Help/Api/GET-api-Surveys-getSurveyPublicResults-id_from_till?apiType=private&renderType=desktop

[https://api.surveyjs.io/private/Surveys/getSurveyPublicResults/{id}?from={from}&till={till}](https://api.surveyjs.io/private/Surveys/getSurveyPublicResults/%7Bid%7D?from=%7Bfrom%7D&till=%7Btill%7D)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make sure your request has an "Accept" header with a value of "application/json".

For example, if you are using jQuery you could do something like this:

```
var settings = {
  "url": "https://api.surveyjs.io/private/Surveys/getSurveyPublicResults/{id}?from={from}&till={till}",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```